# Css. border for single position

Tags: css, border

I am going to explain with the image. [link.](http://www.1907.net/images/border.jpg) When i try to add border position 1 in image. it is adding automatically to 2 and 3. code: `border-bottom: 1px dotted rgb(153, 153, 153)` whey are in thesame line in style sheet. Is there any way to add border to only position 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
div.divclass:first-child {border-bottom: 1px dotted rgb(153, 153, 153)}
```

or

```
div.divclass:nth-child(1) {border-bottom: 1px dotted rgb(153, 153, 153)}
```

EDIT

Alternatively, if you don't want to use classes, you can use your DOM structure to target the DIV:

```
/* Where the second "div" is the element you want to apply the style to */
div > div:first-child {/* Enter style here */}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but i am not good with coding. the 284th line in css is `.info, #commentswrapper ol.commentlist li p.info   { font-size: 100%; overflow: hidden; clear: none; width: auto; }
` how am i going to add border to first position. how to split it with others.

Comment: @1907 .info, #commentswrapper ol.commentlist li p.info:first-child {/* Add styles here */} should do it.

Comment: i paste the code under the original one. but still no good. you see from www.gelsor.com . thanks for your help

Comment: i am trying everything but i cant do it :(

Comment: @1907 Um... OK. In that case do this, write `.info, #commentswrapper ol.commentlist li p.info:first-child {**border-bottom:none** /*Other Styles*/}` then this one under it `.info, #commentswrapper ol.commentlist li p.info:first-child {**border-bottom:1px dotted rgb(153, 153, 153)**}`

Comment: still nothing man. i bealive its my curse. i cant do such a simple thing

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Hr:

```
hr {
  border-top: 1px dotted #f00;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 1px;
  width:50%;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but i am not good with coding. the 284th line in css is `.info, #commentswrapper ol.commentlist li p.info   { font-size: 100%; overflow: hidden; clear: none; width: auto; }
` how am i going to add border to first position. how to split it with others.